# Sign in with linked in error after download app from app store

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I have generated and added debug and release key hashes to the linked in portal. These builds are working without any issue.

But when I installed the app from play store I am not able to sign in using the linked in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Google's App signing, google play signs the app using different key. you need to download signing key from google play developer console (Release Management > App Signing). Then you have to generate key hash from downloaded key.

Once you downloaded the key it will download as a file, (with file name like `deployment_cert.der`)

Then you can use following command(tried on a mac) to generate the key hash.

`cat deployment_cert.der | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`

Then you can add generated key to the linkedin developer account.